# How to make form elements look consistent across all browsers and operating systems

Tags: javascript, html, css

All form elements look different in different browsers.  I want to make it look same.

Comment: You want them to look the same? Too bad you can't. The closest thing you can get are those [`reset.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Answer (score 2):

That's not really possible. Toolkits like Bootstrap are the closest we have to a balance between native controls and consistent controls. Solutions that offer consistent controls will basically use heavy styling to hide the original controls (selects, checkboxes, etc.) and JavaScript to simulate the interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just have to manually check from browser to browser to see what's not looking correct and make changes accordingly.  CSS hacks help, but are kind of ugly 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/